# Can't click bar button on Tool bar?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

In my iPad app, i add navigation bar and tool bar manually.
I also add scroll view and image view by coding.

My problem is i can see both navigation bar and tool bar.
I can click button on navigation bar.
But, i can't click bar button on tool bar.

How can i do it?

This is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UIScrollView *ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    // Create a UIImage to hold Info.png
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-001.jpg"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-002.jpg"];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-003.jpg"];
    UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-004.jpg"];

    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3,image4,nil];

    UIImageView *ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)];
    [ImageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

    [ScrollView addSubview:ImageView];
}

ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:ScrollView];
}
```

Comment: Instead of the code you posted, please show the code related to the toolbar.

Comment: @rmaddy, i'm sorry for my incomplete question, i add tool bar manually. then i add three button on this tool bar also manually. (Not from code). And i connect this buttons with their related view controller. If i click button A, it connect with view controller A. (I connect them with segue - modal). I can see my tool bar, but i can't click button on it. That is my problem. Can i solve it?

Comment: It looks like the scroll view you add covers all but the very top of the view controller's view. The scroll view is on top of the toolbar. This will block any tap events from getting to the toolbar. If you added the toolbar and navbar in Interface Builder, why not also add the scrollview in Interface Builder? Then you make sure it doesn't overlap the toolbar.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for your help. Please, let me ask one question. I can reduce upper part of scroll view. So, i can click button on navigation bar. How can i also reduce lower part of scroll view?

Comment: Set the scroll view's frame properly. It needs to be smaller than the view controller's view size. You also need to be sure to set the scroll view's `autoresizingMask` properly.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks you. I appreciate your help. I reduce my scroll view size. Now, i can solve my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont Know what is your exact problem, Because your displayed code is not related to `UIToolBar`.

But Following code i added two  `UIBarButton` with **flexSpace**.
**you can add `UIBarButton` as you want**

```
UIToolbar *Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    Toolbar = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [Toolbar sizeToFit];

     NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    [flexSpace release];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Cancel)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done)];
    [barItems addObject:btnDone];

    [Toolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
```

**Following Method is call when tapped on bar Button**

```
-(void)Cancel
{
  // Write Code for Cancel Method
}

-(void)done
{
  // Write Code for Done Method
}
```

This code might helpful in your own case.

Thanks :)

Comment: i'm sorry for my incomplete question, i add tool bar manually. then i add three button on this tool bar also manually. (Not from code). And i connect this buttons with their related view controller. If i click button A, it connect with view controller A. (I connect them with segue - modal). I can see my tool bar, but i can't click button on it. That is my problem. Can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I can solve my problem.
I change my code.

```
UIScrollView *ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

To this.

```
UIScrollView *ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)];
```

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the `88` value. You should get the actual heights of the navbar and toolbar. And don't forget to set the scroll view's `autoresizingMask`. Other wise the scroll view's size won't change if the view controller's size changes (such as when rotating to/from landscape.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks you. You really help me. I plan to rotate my view orientation. I forget to thought about orientation. Your guide line is very important for me. Thanks you very much.